# What program can I use to open an .itf file? (interlace file)

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format

After looking around for a couple hours, I can only find that files with this extension are associated with JPI TopSpeed Pascal.

The files were generated by a cable tester and I have no idea what the model number of said tester is.

Essentially, I was given a number of files by someone at work and asked, "How do I open these?"

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks, all.

Comment: Instead of spending hours looking for what opens a particular format, Wotsit can be useful: http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?search=itf&button=GO!

Comment: Thanks for the info, @aking1012. Although it didn't help with this particular problem I'm definitely going to keep it in mind.

Comment: Topspeed Pascal is a dos/win16 pascal compiler which together with the Modula2 version of that line were quite popular in 16-bit times. .itf files are probably "interface files" and as such a kind of header files, not actual code. Probably the code is stuffed top till bottom with 16-bitisms and dosisms, so unless you have the compiler (hard to come by nowadays), the only thing you can do is try to understand it and rewrite in something else.

Comment: OLD question, couldn't even remember posting this. Thanks for the reply, @MarcovandeVoort. Has since been resolved, I believe. (Or is no longer an issue.)

Answer (score 1):

Can they be files used by [Interlis](http://www.interlis.ch/index_e.htm)? If yes, I think that you should use it to manipulate them.
On that site there are some examples too.
Unfortunately, it seems only for Windows.

Comment: I'm leaning toward these files not being related to Interlis. They were generated by a cable tester (telecommunications equipment).